Java ring configuration socket communication gets scrambled up
I have this code:
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Node {
    private String serverIpAddress;
    private String nextHopIpAddress;
    private int nextHopPort;

    private ServerSocket nodeServerSocket;
    private Socket nextNodeSocket;

    public Node(String serverIpAddress, int serverPort, String nextHopIpAddress, int nextHopPort) {
        this.serverIpAddress = serverIpAddress;
        this.nextHopIpAddress = nextHopIpAddress;
        this.nextHopPort = nextHopPort;

        try {
            nodeServerSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort, 10, InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress));
            System.out.println("Server is listening on " + serverIpAddress + ":" + serverPort);

            new Thread(() -> {
               while (true) {
                   try {
                       Socket incomingConnection = nodeServerSocket.accept();
                       handleIncomingConnections(incomingConnection);
                   } catch (IOException exception) {
                       exception.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
            }).start();

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleIncomingConnections(Socket incomingConnection) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            InputStream inputStream = incomingConnection.getInputStream();

            int bytesRead = inputStream.readNBytes(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            int receivedValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getInt();

            System.out.println(serverIpAddress + " received " + receivedValue + " from " + incomingConnection.getInetAddress());

            if (receivedValue == 100) {
                closeConnections();
                return;
            }

            sendData(++receivedValue);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendData(int value) {
        try {
            if (nextNodeSocket == null || nextNodeSocket.isClosed() || !nextNodeSocket.isConnected()) {
                nextNodeSocket = new Socket(nextHopIpAddress, nextHopPort);
                System.out.println(serverIpAddress + " connected to " + nextHopIpAddress);
            }

            OutputStream outputStream = nextNodeSocket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println(serverIpAddress + " sent " + value + " to " + nextHopIpAddress);

            outputStream.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array());

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeConnections() {
        try {
            if (nextNodeSocket != null && !nextNodeSocket.isClosed()) {
                nextNodeSocket.close();
            }

            if (nodeServerSocket != null && !nodeServerSocket.isClosed()) {
                nodeServerSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node1 = new Node("127.0.0.1", 2345, "127.0.0.2", 3456);
        new Node("127.0.0.2", 3456, "127.0.0.3", 4567);
        new Node("127.0.0.3", 4567, "127.0.0.1", 2345);

        node1.sendData(1);
    }
}

The purpose of this code is to resemble a ring communication like this:

127.0.0.1 starts the communication by sending to the next node the value 1, and each node will increment the value until it reaches 100, then the communication should stop and the connections should be closed. When a connection is established it should remain open until the communication stops. This is my output when I run this program:
Server is listening on 127.0.0.1:2345
Server is listening on 127.0.0.2:3456
Server is listening on 127.0.0.3:4567
127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.2
127.0.0.1 sent 1 to 127.0.0.2
127.0.0.2 received 1 from /127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2 connected to 127.0.0.3
127.0.0.2 sent 2 to 127.0.0.3
127.0.0.3 received 2 from /127.0.0.1
127.0.0.3 connected to 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.3 sent 3 to 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 received 3 from /127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 sent 4 to 127.0.0.2

Everything looks good until "127.0.0.3 sent 3 to 127.0.0.1" and "127.0.0.1 received 3 from /127.0.0.1". How can 127.0.0.1 receive from itself? And after the last line the program seems to be stuck. What am I doing wrong here?

You need nextNodeSocket = new Socket(nextHopIpAddress, nextHopPort, InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress), 0);, otherwise the socket can have the local IP address of 127.0.0.1, but there are other problems. You need a read loop inside handleIncomingConnections(), which BTW should be renamed to handleIncomingConnection().

Your suggestions worked! But I can't understand, why can the socket have the local IP address? In what circumstances does that happen?

127.0.0.1 can connect to 127.0.0.2..255, because of the default internal routing (same subnet). So 127.0.0.1 is liable to be chosen as the outbound socket's local IP address. In your case you want it to be the same IP address the node is listening at. Code will probably still work without setting the outbound IP address, but the output will be confusing.
